# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dotnetcli.azureedge.net

Tags: visual-studio, maui

After upgrading to Visual Studio 17.8 Preview 4, I cannot connect to my Mac to build my .NET MAUI App.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I always get this message and wait and wait, but nothing happens in the end and I cannot connect to my Mac.

Also did a Rollback of the above update to the previous one I had installed (Visual Studio 17.8 Preview 2).

Unfortunately, this did not help and even worse, I even can't connect to my Mac with the Previous Version which used to work before :(

Yet another update that just left chaos in my installation.

Is there anything I can do to get this working again and to be able to connect to my Mac to build my .NET MAUI App?

Comment: It's suggested to report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see [How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201)

Comment: Strange for me to see that every time I do an update of VS something different does not work anymore or breaks. Annoying to see for me as from the past I was used to high quality standards :(

Comment: Yes, it's annoying to see this issue, however, you can try to uninstall it and reinstall it to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom dns server, for example pi-hole to block ads?

I had a similar issue today with pi-hole.

I could test with nslookup on WSL, should work the same with Mac.

The following response is with pi-disabled (nameserver is 192.168.1.3), and you can see that dotnetcli.azureedge.net is resolved to a valid ip address:

```
$  nslookup dotnetcli.azureedge.net
Server:         192.168.1.3
Address:        192.168.1.3#53

Non-authoritative answer:
dotnetcli.azureedge.net canonical name = dotnetcli.ec.azureedge.net.
dotnetcli.ec.azureedge.net      canonical name = cs9.wpc.v0cdn.net.
Name:   cs9.wpc.v0cdn.net
Address: 152.199.19.161
Name:   cs9.wpc.v0cdn.net
Address: 2606:2800:133:206e:1315:22a5:2006:24fd
```

However, with pi-hole, enabled (nameserver = 192.168.1.27, my dns query does not resolve to an ip address.

```
$ nslookup dotnetcli.azureedge.net
Server:         192.168.1.27
Address:        192.168.1.27#53

Non-authoritative answer:
dotnetcli.azureedge.net canonical name = dotnetcli.ec.azureedge.net.
dotnetcli.ec.azureedge.net      canonical name = cs9.wpc.v0cdn.net.
```

This is despite the fact that pi-hole is telling me that is it not blocking this address.

The resolution for me was to block and then unblock the hostname in pi-hole.

For you, a dns server recycle might do the trick

Hope that helps.